# WordPress live domain error

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I have made a fully operating WP site locally on my computer(whit xampp and localhost). I wanted to add whit site to a live domain using the xampps `vhosts.conf` file. For the 1st time the site's main page loaded perfectly but after that no other part of the site will load, not even the style sheet.

Any suggestions what to do?

Thanks

This is what i have added to the vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example<br>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/WP"<br>
    ServerName /*Actual server name*/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the path of home and siteurl in 'wp-options' table in your database.
you can take further help from wordpress site https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!